# Are the parts in bold examples of relative clauses?

Tags: relative-clauses

I have these two sentences as examples:

> They seem a little concerned about the direction [that] **we're taking**.

If I'm not mistaken, *about the direction we're taking* is an adverb prepositional phrase because it modifies the adjective *concerned*, and prepositional phrases can have multiple elements inside it.

> The thing [that] **I wish for most** is that people would all just get along.

Now the focus on the subject, so *I wish for most* seems to be describing *the thing*.

Are both of these parts of the sentence relative clauses because of how they modify and follow nouns? If so, a *that* could be introducing them, right?

Comment: yes, you are right. both of these are defining relative clauses.

Comment: Yes, they are relative clauses. They qualify as relatives because they have a (covert) relativised element which is anaphorically linked to the head nouns "direction" and "thing". I used the word covert because "that" is a subordinator, not a relative pronoun.

Comment: Great! I very much appreciate it.